# Eclipse "cannot perform nested evaluation" error when there is no nested evaluation

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, apache-camel, display

I'm using Eclipse to debug a Java Program.
I'm at a breakpoint in a method that looks roughly like this

```
void the_method(final Exchange exchange) {

    final String filename = exchange.getIn().getHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME, String.class);

    final String fileNameRegEx = exchange.getIn().getHeader(Constants.FILE_NAME_REGEX, String.class);
--- breakpoint here ---
    if (filename.matches(fileNameRegEx)) {
        // stuff
    } else {
        // more stuff
    }
}
```

Now I'm trying to see what the result of filename.matches(fileNameRegex) will be, so I go in the Display tab and I type it, but then I get :

```
filename.matches(fileNameRegEx)
    Evaluation failed. Reason(s):
        Cannot perform nested evaluations.
```

same if I just so little as type the name of some local variable and do the same thing (granted it's useless because the variables view is there for this, but still) :

```
filename
    Evaluation failed. Reason(s):
        Cannot perform nested evaluations.
```

How is inspecting the variable a nested evaluation of anything ?

I'm confused. I used to use IntelliJ and the cited things where all possible without any trouble.
I'm not trying to flame Eclipse in any way, I've grown to really like Eclipse, I just want to understand what is causing this.

Thank you :)

edit 1 :

to answer the comments, yes this happens for ALL local variables, and the content of the regex is

```
"^FileName_2018_[0-9A-Z\\-]{20}_(THING|STUFF)-[A-Z][0-9]{7}_[0-9]{4}_[0-9]{10}.zip$"
```

edit : bump ? I can't be the only one hindered from this can I ? :(

Comment: Can you give a specific example of a variable evaluation that gives the same error? Does this happen for all variables? Or just for some?

Comment: What is the content of your regular expression?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice , khelwood , I answered your comments in my "edit 1"

Comment: I found a bug regarding this message maybe this is relevant in your case?https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=77543

Comment: @TomaszWida Yes I stumbled upon it while googling this too, but it doesn't seem to provide much help as the bug was deemed "irreproductible" and no fix was made... plus it's dated November 2004 !